# How to get Spring 3.1.1 works with App Engine datastore

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Could everyone show me a tutorial on how to make Spring 3.1.1 running on Google App Engine, please?

I've followed severals tutorial and managed to get the dead simple HelloWorld example to work on App Engine. However, when I go futher, I stuck at the persistent process between Spring and Datastore. I looked at this thread [Configuring JDO in Spring 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853133/configuring-jdo-in-spring-3-1), too, but it works on localhost but it doesn't work when I deploy to app engine due to the javax.naming.NamingException.

Therefore, I'm looking for a not-too-simple tutorial that covers basic aspects of a real life application such as the view, the model and the database.

Comment: Could you post the exception and the code which causes it?

Comment: I've got:  

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException
 at  
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
 at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  

But the author of the example I mentioned above has fixed it, so it's ok for now.

Answer (score 0):

[Jappstart](http://code.google.com/p/jappstart/) is a good place to see a working example of GAE that uses Spring and the Datastore (via JPA) and is also a good starting point for building a basic GAE/J app.

Comment: Thank you,  
I'll take a look at it, seems promising!

Answer (score 0):

Having spent about a day trying to make this work, I thought I'd add some additional useful information here. First take a look at this project https://github.com/hleinone/spring-gae-jdo and this issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1240 -- comment 24 is the useful one.

In case anyone wants to get this working with annotation-driven configuration, here's how I did it:

```
package com.domain.yourcode.configuration;

import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.jdo.GAETransactionAwarePersistenceManagerFactoryProxy;
import org.springframework.orm.jdo.JdoTransactionManager;
//import org.springframework.orm.jdo.TransactionAwarePersistenceManagerFactoryProxy;

@Configuration
public class JDOConfiguration {

    private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmf =     JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    @Bean
    public GAETransactionAwarePersistenceManagerFactoryProxy proxyPmf() {
        GAETransactionAwarePersistenceManagerFactoryProxy proxy = 
                new GAETransactionAwarePersistenceManagerFactoryProxy();
        proxy.setTargetPersistenceManagerFactory(pmf);
        proxy.setAllowCreate(false);
        return proxy;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdoTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JdoTransactionManager mgr = new JdoTransactionManager();
        mgr.setPersistenceManagerFactory(pmf);
        return mgr;
    }

}
```

You'll still want `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in your applicationContext.xml