# Working Spring 3.2.5 + JDO 3.0 + GAE configuration

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have tried searching online and found [Configuring JDO in Spring 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853133/configuring-jdo-in-spring-3-1) or  https://github.com/tomhowe/wicket-spring-jdo-interfaces but this projects are dated. Can anyone help me with a working pom.xml and applicationContext.xml? I have a working pom.xml that allows me to use the persistanceManager https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2 but I would like to handle transactions with spring's @Transactional

Comment: Are you sure all standard-JDK classes that Spring uses are on the GAE white list: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist   When I tried doing a Spring 3.0 GAE project (true, it was a good while back), this wasn't the case.

Comment: Spring security and framework work, you can take a look here https://github.com/archie-sh/google-app-engine-jappstart